# How to Verify Email if user use phone to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, verification

User registers on my website and they need to approve their email. User goes to gmail (for example) on phone and they need again to login and again to send verification message. How to solve this problem?

my routes:

```
Route::prefix('/email')
    ->name('verification.')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/verify', function () {
            return view('notifications::email');
        })->middleware('auth')->name('notice');

        Route::get('/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
            $request->fulfill();
            return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('success', '');
        })->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verify');

        Route::post('/verification-notification', function (Request $request) {
            $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
            return back()->with('success', '');
        })->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])->name('send');
    });
```

At the moment, on my website, the User logs in automatically, but this solution only works on the PC. Because he is authorized.

My register controller now:

```
public function create(UserRegisterRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $user = User::create([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'name' => $request->name,
        'password' => \Hash::make($request->password)
    ]);

    event(new Registered($user));

    auth()->login($user);

    return response()->redirectTo(route('posts.index'))->with(
        'success',
        "{$request->email}"
    );
}
```

I have only one thought in my head how to solve this problem, allow the user to confirm mail without authorization, but I do not like this approach

Comment: you dont need to make the route use `auth` middleware. the `{hash}` in `Route::get('/verify/{id}/{hash}')` is doing the identification of that specific email already. unless you are not using the default route, and using `Route::get('/verify')` which you should not do.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I did it according to the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/verification#the-email-verification-handler

Comment: I tried to delete `auth` in route `Route::get('/verify/{id}/{hash}')`. Now i have crash in this method 
```public function authorize() {
        if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('id'),
                          (string) $this->user()->getKey())) {
            return false;
        }```

Comment: The email verification from the documentation is not the one you need. the one in the docs insures that the **logged in** user verifies his email while you want to send an **autologin** email that verifies the email no matter if the user is logged in or **not**. choose another solution that send a link with a token for autologin.

Comment: Thanks for explain me! Now i understand what to need to do. I want approve your answer . How to do it in comment? :) You solve my problem.

Comment: no need, you can delete the question, I dont think it can be salvaged for future reference. The important thing is that you got your answer :)

Comment: One question. How safe is it?

Comment: If you generate a jwt token with an expiration of 24 hours, it is pretty secure. You need to secure the link to verify the email with jwt-auth.